# d3.js data imported but bar chart not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I was trying to make a bar chart using the data from a csv file. It has two columns: `year` / `running_total`

| year | running_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1884 | 1 |
| ... | ... |
| 1969 | 50710 |
| ... | ... |

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <style>
    <!-- define CSS rules -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/d3-dsv/d3-dsv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/d3-fetch/d3-fetch.min.js"></script>

  
  <script>
    // define the dimensions and margins for the graph
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 80},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        padding = 0.5;

    // define function to parse time in years format
    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y")

    // create scales x & y for X and Y axis and set their ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range ([margin.left+padding, width-padding]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range ([height, 0]);


    // append svg element to the body of the page
    // set dimensions and position of the svg element
    var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    var pathToCsv = "q3.csv";       // path to csv
    
    d3.dsv(",", pathToCsv, function (d) {
      return {
        // format data attributes if required
        year: parseTime(d.year),
        running_total: +d.running_total
      }
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log(data); // you should see the data in your browser's developer tools console 
      
      /* Create bar plot using data from csv */

      // set the domains of X and Y scales based on data
      x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.running_total; })]);

      // Add bars to svg - create new elements based on your data
      svg.selectAll("rect")
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append("rect")
         .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
         .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.running_total); })
         .attr("width", width/data.length - padding)
         .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.running_total); })
         .attr("fill", "steelblue");

      // Add the X Axis
      //svg.append()

      // Add the text label for X Axis
      //svg.append()

      // Add the Y Axis
      //svg.append()

      // Add the text label for Y axis
      //svg.append()


    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });


  </script>

</body>
```

I can see data imported correctly but I'm not sure why there is no graph displaying.

Comment: Are there any errors popping up?

Comment: @rguttersohn no. that's  the part that quite confusing to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you are passing an array of all the years

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
```

You need to pass the min/ max of the years in the data to `x.domain()` - you can use [`d3.extent`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#extent) to do this:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.year}));
```

Here's an example:

```js
// define the dimensions and margins for the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  padding = 0.5;

// define function to parse time in years format
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y")

// create scales x & y for X and Y axis and set their ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range ([margin.left+padding, width-padding]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range ([height, 0]);
  
// append svg element to the body of the page
// set dimensions and position of the svg element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

/* Create bar plot using data from csv */
var data = [];
var rt = 10;
for (let i=1850; i<1875; i++) {
  data.push({
    "year": parseTime(i),
    "running_total": rt
  });
  rt += Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
  
// set the domains of X and Y scales based on data
//x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }));
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.year}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){return d.running_total; })]);

// Add bars to svg - create new elements based on your data
svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.running_total); })
  .attr("width", width/data.length - padding)
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y( d.running_total); })
  .attr("fill", "steelblue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```